# Render in the background?

Tags: pitivi

How can I set Pitivi to render in the background and let me work on another project in the meantime? Being able to launch a second process (window) would also be acceptable.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Launching a second Pitivi instance can be done only with the latest master. Please wait for the next release, or if you want to help testing it, install it with flatpak: http://developer.pitivi.org/Install_with_flatpak.html